# x64 Intel Opcode 81 /2

Tags: 64-bit, machine-code

How does the processor differentiate between these two instructions?

81 /2 iw - Add with carry imm16 to r/m16.

81 /2 id - Add with carry imm32 to r/m32.

The only thing different I can see in the instruction is the size of the immediate value and that isn't enough, right?  I mean if the immediate is two bytes an instruction could be right after it and the processor wouldn't know if it was 4 bytes of immediate or 2 bytes and another instruction.

Also am I supposed to add a REX prefix to these for 64-bit operation or just REX.R for the 9-16 registers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mode and operand size prefix. In 16 bit mode, 81 /2 will be `adc rm16, imm16`. In 32 or 64 bit mode, it will be `adc rm32, imm32`. Unless you add the operand size override, then they switch places.

To make it `adc rm64, imm32` (there is no `adc rm64, imm64`), it needs an REX.W prefix, REX.R is useless since there is no r operand, REX.B/X will just allow you to use extended registers as (part of) the rm operand, and don't change the operand size. So for example `adc r8d, 0xDEADBEEF` is valid and would be `41 81 D0 EF BE AD DE`.

Comment: So in 64-bit mode there's no way to use a 16 bit register?

Comment: and why does it say the 16-bit instruction is valid in 64-bit mode?

Comment: If you add the operand size override, it becomes `adc rm16, imm16` in 32 bit and 64 bit modes.

Comment: I'm sorry, which operand size override?

Comment: @RyanBrown the 0x66 prefix

Comment: What if I want to use the 9-16 16-bit registers?  Do I combine REX.B with 0x66?  So the prefix would be 0x67?

Comment: @RyanBrown they're not combined that way (0x67 is the address size override by the way, and other nearby bytes have very different meanings), you just have to use both prefixes (the REX prefix goes directly in front of the opcode, so 0x66 has to come first)

Comment: @RyanBrown the REX prefixes are 0x40 .. 0x4F